# QGIS legend without print composer

Tags: qgis, legend, timemanager

I'm trying to export a series of images using the TimeManager plugin.

I'd like to have a legend on each, to demonstrate why my datapoints are sized the way that they are (i.e. this circle size represents one square foot, this circle size represents ten square feet).

Is it possible to add and style a legend in base QGIS? I do not want to use Print Composer as that won't work well with TimeManager.

I am fairly new to QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the legend rendered in the main map window.

One approach to generate a video with legend would be to add an image containing the legend to the video using video processing software.

Comment: Thought that might be the case. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate a dummy 'legend' dataset reflecting your data classes that you can label, position away from the action, and persist through time so that it is constantly shown in the TimeManager stills?